# OpenvSwitch Spanning-tree priority for specific Vlan ID

Tags: vlan, spanning-tree, sdn, ovs

I'm new to the SDN technology,
I have 12 year's experience working with Cisco products,

On Cisco devices, a user can set different STP priority Per VLAN ID
Like :

```
Switch(config)#spanning-tree VLAN 10 priority 32768
```

On OpenvSwitch STP priority could be set on BRIDGE but not per VLAN!

```
ovs-vsctl set Bridge br0 other_config:stp-priority=32768
```

Is there any way to set priority for specific VLAN ID like vlan 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The per-VLAN spanning tree concept (PVST, PVST+, RPVST+) is proprietary Cisco and only a few other vendors support it - OVS doesn't.

The IEEE Multiple Spanning-Tree Protocol (MSTP) allows running multiple instances (each with its own spanning tree) which you can group your VLANs into. This isn't supported by OVS either.

RSTP is supported but it's 'flat' in regard to VLANs - there's only a single instance and no way to utilize redundant links. You can only set global bridge and port priorities.

However, OVS does support Shortest Path Bridging MAC (802.1aq) which is superior to STP - you should give it a look. Interfacing your physical switches with STP and the OVS structure with SPB may prove difficult though.

Answer (score 2):

[Current documentation of OVS](http://docs.openvswitch.org/en/latest/faq/issues/?highlight=spanning%20tree) suggests that spanning tree is

> The Open vSwitch implementation of STP is not well tested.

And documentation does not make any reference to the known protocols hat support multiple spanning tree instances such as MST (802.1s) or the Cisco proprietary PVST, PVST+ or Rapid-PVST+

However, there seems to be support for Rapid-STP, as per 
http://www.openvswitch.org/support/dist-docs/ovs-vsctl.8.txt, but still no mentioning of any of the more advanced multiple spanning tree protocols.

Probably, you're out of luck, here.

Comment: Yor are right, here some desc from OVS maling-list, The cisco is using PVST (Per VLAN Spanning Tree), while OVS only
supports basic 802.1d.  You will either have to configure the cisco to
use 802.1d, or figure out if PVST has a compatibility mode.  Or, of
course, you could simply not build a loop thus making spanning tree
unnecessary. 
https://mail.openvswitch.org/pipermail/ovs-discuss/2012-July/027505.html